# How to return to the same page in django

Tags: python, django

I have added react to my videos in my project. After reacting on the post i want to stay in the same page.

here's all videos template

```
<figcaption class="info-wrap">
                    <h6 class="title"><a href="{% url 'singlevideo' pk=video.pk cpk=video.category.id %}">{{video.title}}</a></h6>
                    <i style="color:black; font-size:12px;">@{{video.creator}} || {{video.upload_date}}||{{video.category}}</i>
                    <div class="action-wrap">
                        <div class="price-wrap h5">
```

after clicking on the title it takes to the page of the video

```
http://localhost:8000/videos/9/5/
```

and the single video template

```
<figcaption class="info-wrap">
                <div style="padding:20px;">
                {% if video.pk in like_post %}
                <a href="{% url 'unliked' pk=video.pk %}"><i class="fa fa-heart" style="font-size:36px;"></i></a>
                {% else %}
                <a href="{% url 'liked' pk=video.pk %}"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" style="font-size:36px;"></i></a>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
```

views.py

```
def liked(request,pk):
    post= Uploads.objects.get(pk=pk)
    already_liked=Like.objects.filter(post=post,user=request.user)
    if not already_liked:
        liked_post=Like(post=post,user=request.user)
        liked_post.save()
        return redirect('/')
        

def Unilked(request,pk):
    post= Uploads.objects.get(pk=pk)
    already_liked=Like.objects.filter(post=post,user=request.user)
    already_liked.delete()
    return redirect('/')
```

models.py

```
class Like(models.Model):
    post=models.ForeignKey(Uploads,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='like_post')
    user= models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='liker')
    date_created= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __st__(self):
        return str(self.user)+' liked '+str(self.post)
```

urls.py

```
from cmath import sin
from django.urls import path
from Videos.views import Uploader,show_video,single_video,liked,Unilked
urlpatterns = [
    path('upload/',Uploader,name="upload_video"),
    path('',show_video,name="show_video"),
    path('<int:pk>/<int:cpk>/', single_video,name="singlevideo"),
    path('liked/<int:pk>/',liked,name="liked"),
    path('unliked/<int:pk>/',Unilked,name="unliked"),
]
```

i want to stay on the same page after reacting. But the problem is singlevideo take 'pk' and 'cpk' . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

***i want to stay on the same page after reacting.*** - you can use `redirect(request.path)`

```
def Unilked(request,pk):
    post= Uploads.objects.get(pk=pk)
    already_liked=Like.objects.filter(post=post,user=request.user)
    already_liked.delete()
    return redirect(request.path)
```

Comment: It finally worked. I accepted pk and cpk when i am reacting on any video, then i have added kwargs on views ```return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('singlevideo', kwargs={'pk':pk,'cpk':cpk}))```